# Тернарная операция ? : Как работает?

Tags: c++

Пишу я, значит, лабу - надо организовать двойную очередь шаблонным классом и продемонстрировать работу в main() - и тут до меня доходит, что я не знаю, как работает тернарная операция ?:

```
template<class TInfo>
const TInfo& TDeque<TInfo>::GetFront() const
{
     return front ? front->info : 0;
}
```

Когда вызывал этот метод из main() для своего класса Man, то вызывался конструктор копирования последнего в строчке return front ? front->info : 0; , а потом ещё и деструктор! В результате программа вылетала (ну не должно было там ничего вызываться!). Но ведь возвращаю я по ссылке!!! После двухчасового безрезультатного поиска ошибок данную функцию переписал:

```
template<class TInfo>
const TInfo& TDeque<TInfo>::GetFront() const
{
        if(front) 
            return front->info;
        return 0;
}
```

И всё работает!!! Никакие конструкторы/деструкторы не вызываются!

В чём отличие и почему первая так странно себя вела?

Comment: А как у Вас переменная `front` определена?

Из текста вопроса не понятно.

Comment: Вообще-то, непонятно, почему это работает.

0 ведь ни с какой стороны не `TInfo&`.

Comment: @zer_ik, А можете весь код выложить?

Comment: Попробуйте NULL вместо 0

Comment: @Deadkenny, NULL будет аналогичен 0 в C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В первом случае вызывается конструктор копирования TInfo(front->info) или конструктор TInfo(0) - тернарной операции надо второе и третье выражения обязательно привести к одному типу, если это возможно. Она это и делает. Поэтому получается, что возвращается ссылка на временный анонимный стековый объект в любом случае, даже вместо front->info.

Во втором случае необходимость создания анонимного экземпляра возникает только в return 0;
, что оказывается эквивалентно return TInfo(0); .

В обоих случаях, видимо, не выдается предупреждение, т.к. возвращается const TInfo&.

UPD: "видимо" - потому что не компилировал, нет сейчас возможности.

Comment: @paulgri, вы уверены, что результатом тернарной операции будет именно TInfo, a не const TInfo& ?

Comment: @paulgri, проверил, действительно конструктор копирования вызывается в тернарном операторе.

Comment: @dzhioev, уверен, т.к. при неявном создании объекта в тернарной операции ничего явно не говорит о const, а константным объект считается на "принимающей" стороне, где запрещено изменение этого объекта.

Comment: Но вообще здесь проблема в логике - если функция возвращает ссылку, то это должна быть ссылка на долгоживущий объект, а если невозможно, то генерировать исключение. Это будет правильное и предсказуемое поведение функции. Временные экземпляры долго не живут, тогда как ссылка может существовать долго и происходит попытка использовать несуществующий объект. Думаю, TC надо посмотреть на структуру TInfo и как он используется после вызова этой функции.

Comment: Встречал еще более хитрую вещь. Люди хотели сделать map с поддержкой дефолтного значения. Метод Get выглядел примерно так:
    
    const Value& Get(const Key& key, const Value& default) const {
        auto it = impl_.find(key);
        if (it != impl_.end())
            return it->second;
        return default;
    }

Проблема возникает, когда мы передаем в default ссылку на временный объект:

    if (my_map.Get(key, Value()) == some_value) {
    
Получается, что когда key не найден, мы возвращаем ссылку на объект, который к моменту сравнения с some_value может быть уже разрушен.

Comment: Ну и существует малоизвестная вещь в C++ -- продление жизни временного объекта при помощи ссылки на него. Следующий код полностью корректный:

    Object DoSomething();

    int main() {
        const Object& ref = DoSomething();
        // .. do another stuff ..
        ref.CallMethod();
    }

Ссылка ref продлевает время жизни временного объекта, который вернула функция DoSomething, до момента выхода из scope, в котором ref определенна. У Саттера на эту тему хорошо написано: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/205848/) статейку на Хабре и многие вопросы я думаю отпадут

Comment: Хорошая иллюстрация тезиза -- почему не стоит писать на на С++.